# Working with non-unicode text in Haskell

Tags: haskell, character-encoding, text-processing

I feel like there is a bit of a debate in the Haskell community about `String` vs `Data.Text`, but in my mind they both suffer from the same deficiency - namely that they don't represent all textual data, just Unicode text.

The only project I've found that deals with character encodings is the aptly named [encoding](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/encoding) package, but it seems to only support conversion to/from Unicode, without providing any mechanisms for text processing in those encodings.

Is there a project out there that is trying to get a new typeclass (`Textual`?) that different character encodings could be instances of, so that I could do text processing directly with UTF-8 just as easily as with, say GB-2312?

---

As for @bergey's comment, it's not that I'm trying to work with characters that aren't part of Unicode. All of the non-Unicode files that I encounter typically use established legacy character sets that were included in Unicode.

My issue is more with text functions that were designed to work with non-Unicode text. For example:

- Url percent encoding.

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2) allows percent-encoding and transmission of non-unicode character encodings, and in the real world, there are still people using GB2312/EUC-CN. When a Haskell library only offers unicode percent encoding (eg `Network.HTTP.urlEncode :: String -> String`), it won't work for those apis.

- quoted-printable

Similarly, [quoted-printable](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047#section-4.2) text should be able to represent non-unicode encodings, and I still come across these types of emails. The only library I've found to deal with quoted printable, [`Codec.MIME.Decode`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mime-0.4.0.2/docs/Codec-MIME-Decode.html), also works with Strings, which means it can't deal with these non-Unicode encodings.

I'm certainly not trying to be critical here; I'm mainly interested in finding how to best add support for other types of textual data (and whether or not people are already working on it). In my mind, it would be great for functions like `urlEncode` to able to be written once and retain the type `String -> String`, and be able to handle any type of text string and not just unicode without needing separate implementations for each possible type of text.

---

As for @DanielWagner's comment:

`String` is absolutely specific to certain encodings.

```
[martin@localhost ~]$ echo -n '中文' > utf8text
[martin@localhost ~]$ iconv -f utf8 -t gb2312 utf8text > gb2312text
[martin@localhost ~]$ xxd gb2312text 
00000000: d6d0 cec4                                ....
[martin@localhost ~]$ ghc -e 'readFile "gb2312text"'
<interactive>: gb2312text: hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)
```

The `invalid byte sequence` exception is thrown because the String function is unable to convert these bytes into codepoints.

Comment: Why though? Just read the text as it is, decode, process, and then re-encode. Keeping the text encoded in-process doesn't really buy you anything; If you're dealing with datasources with multiple different encodings and want to make sure you write the right one back just keep the original encoding around like `(DynEncoding, Text)`.

Comment: I don't think this makes sense. Legacy encodings like GB-2312 should be purged entirely. All text should be Unicode, and how it's encoded internally is an implementation detail. (Arguably, it should [always be Utf-8](http://utf8everywhere.org/) which `Text` doesn't use but [`Foundation.String`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foundation-0.0.20/docs/Foundation-String.html) does, but it doesn't really matter because the interface abstracts over this.) Everything else isn't text but _data_, for which there is `ByteString`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout It would be convenient if all text were Unicode, but the reality is that I still run into gb2312 encoded files all the time.

Comment: @Cubic that's what I've been doing. It just hasn't felt right that one type of text gets such preferential treatment over others.

Comment: If you run into gb2312 files then the right thing to do is re-encode them. If you're not allowed to do that, pity, but then at least read them in as Unicode.

Comment: @martin Text encodings aren't a social group. There's no non-discrimination laws for them and there's no ethical reason for there to be any. Unicode and its associated encodings get preferential treatment because they're better than the alternatives.

Comment: @Cubic in fact, one might say Unicode itself is the embodiment of non-discrimination, and using any particular other encoding discriminates against languages that it doesn't cover.

Comment: This kind of fruitless debate is exactly why SO has rules against asking for library recommendations: when the library doesn't exist, everybody argues until they're blue in the face that you shouldn't want it (and will continue to do so right up to the moment that somebody sits down and writes a library, at which point the tune suddenly changes), and when the library does exist, recommendations go out of date because a new library that does the same thing is sure to come along eventually. I encourage future would-be commenters to vote to close and move on.

Comment: @martin "It just hasn't felt right that one type of text gets such preferential treatment over others." That's the idea. The entire purpose of Unicode is to supersede all other encodings, so of course it's going to get preferential treatment.

Comment: Things would get really complicated really quickly if languages supported hundreds of internal encodings, because then every program anyone wrote would need to support all these different encodings. The best way to resolve this would be to have a single generic way to refer to characters regardless of the encoding, while you're working with the text. That "generic interface" is called Unicode.

Comment: Are you actually trying to process texts that contain characters not representable in Unicode?

Comment: @bergey I've updated my question.

Comment: Reading the updated question, I strongly suspect you have misunderstood something. Unicode *is not* an encoding. `String` *is not* specific to any encoding. If you have a function which consumes `String`s, that function will work on your codepoints, no matter which encoding you used to convert bytes into codepoints.

Comment: @DanielWagner I've updated my question.

Comment: @martin You have misdiagnosed your problem. `String` is not specific to an encoding; but `readFile` *is*. So: you should either use GHC's mechanism for affecting what encoding `readFile` uses, or use `Data.ByteString.readFile` to read bytes and another package to convert the bytes to a `String`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Right, I guess what I meant to say there was that libraries that work with strings only work with unicode text. From what I've been able to gather, it does indeed seem that the only option for working with non-unicode text at this point would be to convert it from a ByteString to unicode text as a String or Data.Text.